# Perl alarm() or Time::Out Without Kernel SIG

Tags: perl, cron, timeout, alarm

I have a script which occasionally misbehaves while communicating with a web server. The server hangs or is very slow to respond with data.

I am currently using `alarm()` as a hack to get the script to terminate—so as to not flood the system with threads—but this causes a cron error, which alerts the sysadmin, who really doesn't want the 200 emails this produces when the system has fallen over.

Is there an alternative method of terminating a script (or apiQuery, if need be) that won't cause a non-OK exit and the corresponding email?

Comment: can you post your code? Then we can probably help with a solution.

Comment: or at least add a [mcve] if the code is really big

Comment: (1) yes.  (2) which one do you want?  // Seriosuly, please complete your question with more information.  Some code in the first place.

Comment: Not sure how a code example will make a difference. The issue is finding an alternative to using alarm for timeouts. The code works fine...

`while {true} do`
`alarm(10)`
`something_that_takes_longer_than_10_seconds_and_causes_kernel_alarm()`
`alarm(0)`
`done`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can throw an exception in your signal handler, and catch it elsewhere.

```
my $success = eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Failure" };
    alarm 10;
    do_something_long();
    alarm 0;
    1;
};
if (!$success) {
    warn "Timeout!\n" if $verbose;
    exit 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a shot. I see SIG{ALRM} in there though. Is this still going to cause a kernel alarm? That's what I am trying to avoid. Apologies for the noob questions. I inherited this perl script and I know very little perl.

Comment: It catches the signal, so your program doesn't die of it